# PHP HTML DOM Parse - Can't find element appended javascript

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying get element from a website. But i can't find element append by javascript. Have solution for that problem>
Code here:

```
    $dom = new Dom;
$obj = $dom->loadFromUrl($url);
$element = $obj->find(".c-payment");
echo count($element);
```

Result = 0, but it has on website

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is way too broad. Please take a moment and look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add some code, dude

Comment: $dom = new Dom;
     $obj = $dom->loadFromUrl($url);
        $element = $obj->find(".c-payment-methods");
        echo count($element); //result = 0, but it has on website

Comment: Add some code to your question. NOBODY can read code in a comment

Comment: i'm sory. i just edited

Comment: @D.Sam Can you provide URL? It will help us debugging and identify issue even more.

Comment: here http://www.lazada.vn/

Answer (score 0):

When you reading a web page content with PHP, you are getting only static content (which are providen from a web server). The dinamic part of the content (which will be generated by JavaScript) do not exists at that moment, because PHP do not executes the JavaScript code.
You can try to use [V8 Javascript Engine Integration](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php). But I do not think that you easily can achieve what you want.
Maybe it will be useful for you: https://github.com/scraperlab/browserext

Comment: yes. i known. How to executes the javascript code on that static content?

Comment: thanks @Neodan .i'm trying but i can not add it inside Xampp. You can guide me do it?