# How to extract meta tags in PHP if server denies access?

Tags: php, web-scraping, meta-tags, domxpath

There are so many discussion in the past regarding this. But things have changed a lot. For example in this question

[Get title of website via link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348912/get-title-of-website-via-link)

which has many solution which worked in the past, but doesn't work now when I check some sites like

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-complete-beginners-guide-to-chinese-fonts--cms-23444

I tried all the methods mentioned on the above SO discussion and none worked for this url. But then I tried the same on this page and they got the title of the page.

http://tools.buzzstream.com/meta-tag-extractor

How did they do it? If not PHP is used, then how to get it done in php? Please suggest an answer other than what is mentioned on the above SO discussion, tried all and none of those work for the tutsplus website. DOMXPATH, file_get_contents(),cURL or adding browser header didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works (-;

In this situation was necessary to set `USER_AGENT` because if you send the request without `USER_AGENT` then the response is `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`.

P.S. Always check the errors and responses (-;

```
<?php
function get_title($url){
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Linux / Firefox 29: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');

    $str = curl_exec($c);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); // supports line breaks inside <title>
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); // ignore case
        return $title[1];
    }
}
//Example:
echo get_title("https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-complete-beginners-guide-to-chinese-fonts--cms-23444");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it on local WAMP server (EasyPHP), didn't work but on the production server, it works. However doesn't work for facebook pages. E.g. https://www.facebook.com/facebook . They have graph api for that, but that too now needs token for access, which it didn't need before.

Comment: do you have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872658/php-html-dom-parse-cant-find-element-appended-javascript/44873323 ?

Comment: Tried xpath on production server and vardump returns 'object(DOMXPath)#2 (1) { ["document"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" }' for the following code $doc = new DOMDocument(); @$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-complete-beginners-guide-to-chinese-fonts--cms-23444');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
var_dump($xpath);
echo $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";

Comment: for facebook you need ```preg_match("/\<title[^>]*\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title);```, because the ```title``` tag have ```id``` attribute

Comment: Thanx a lot. It works for facebook. Ill stick to curl with browser header for now.